# Need a Vlookup Adaptation for multiple values concatd

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation, vlookup

in this opportunity i need some support on getting to build a VBA function to extract multiple values under a Vlookup adaptation call which i cant finish it by myself correctly

Initial DB:

```
CODE    Description
824110111841    BRP391
824110112161    BY698P
824110112451    BRP391 
824110112541    BRP392
824110112781    BRP391 
824110112791    BRP391 
824110112801    BRP391
```

Extract info DB2:

```
    CODE    Description Country STOCKS
824110111841    BRP391  Uruguay 100
824110111841    BRP391  Chile   200
824110111841    BRP391  Argentina   32
824110111841    BRP391  Bolivia 45
824110112161    BY698P  Argentina   12
824110112161    BY698P  Uruguay 100
824110112161    BY698P  Peru    120
824110112451    BRP391  Argentina   440
824110112541    BRP392  Argentina   550
824110112781    BRP391  Uruguay 241
824110112781    BRP391  Chile   77
824110112791    BRP391  Peru    222
824110112801    BRP391  Bolivia 100
```

Final desired Output:

```
  CODE  Description STOCKS OVERVIEW
824110111841    BRP391  Uruguay: 100 | Chile: 200 | Argentina: 32 | Bolivia: 45
824110112161    BY698P  Argentina: 12 | Uruguay: 100 | Peru: 120
824110112451    BRP391  Argentina: 440
824110112541    BRP392  Argentina: 550
824110112781    BRP391  Uruguay: 241 | Chile: 77
824110112791    BRP391  Peru: 222
824110112801    BRP391  Bolivia: 100
```

See, what i've done is to get a concatenation of several multiple vlookup matches and join them together.

XX.

Comment: Can the output () have each country and value in a separate cell. like [Uruguay: 100], [Chile: 200], etc.? Or do you want those all in the same cell?

Comment: The result should be in the same cell, hence, the need of concatenation. Thnx

Comment: If that's the case, please show what you've tried so far.  Also, just an FYI, putting those all in one cell will likely cause headaches later if you want to do any analysis on it.  What version of Excel do you have? Perhaps we can put them in each their own cell, then at the end combine in one with `TEXTJOIN()`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out how to finish my idea by myself, im posting to help SO community if by any chance someone needs this function.

```
Option Explicit

Function SLOWMOVER(value As String, WorkRng As Range, col As Long)

Dim rng As Range
Dim Fx As String
Fx = ""
For Each rng In WorkRng
    If rng = value Then
        Fx = Fx & "| " & rng.Offset(0, col - 2) & ": " & rng.Offset(0, col - 1)
    End If
Next
SLOWMOVER = Fx
End Function


''' Credit to extendedoffice.com where i saw a similar example which i adapted to solve my problem.
```

Regards!

P.D: It's been the third post i upload to this community and i always get bad rep, i'd really appreciate to have feedback at least so i can work my inquiries better, not just get badly qualified.